# jQuery countdown and C# repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, countdown

I'm trying to make multiple countdowns, using jQuery in a C# web application.

I have two different dates in my database, which I'm inserting into the javascript. This works fine, but the javascript is using the same date from the DB, and it's probaly because theres only one instance of the javascript, so I need some advice on how to solve this.

Here is the full code.

Markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var count = new Date('<%=Datestring%>');
        var countdown = setInterval(function () {
            $('.countdown').countdown({ until: count, format: 'DHMS' });
            if (count == 0) {
                window.location = 'http://google.com';
            }
            count--;
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>

<asp:Repeater ID="repAuctions" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repAuctions_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Literal ID="litHeading" runat="server" />
            <br/>
            <asp:Literal ID="litCountDown" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Backend:

```
public string Datestring;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        repAuctions.DataSource = AuctionsFactory.GetAllAuctions();
        repAuctions.DataBind();
    }

    protected void repAuctions_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var auction = (Auction)e.Item.DataItem;
        var litCountDown = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litCountDown");
        var litHeading = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litHeading");

        string format = "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        var countdowndate = (DateTime) auction.TimeLeft;
        Datestring = countdowndate.ToString(format);

        litHeading.Text = auction.Heading;
        litCountDown.Text = auction.TimeLeft + "<span class='countdown'></span>";
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to solve. But, it looks like you're re-initializing your countdown on each interval, which probably shouldn't happen. (But then again, I don't know what the `countdown` function looks like)

Comment: I'm trying to output two different countdowns.
Check out this screen:
http://screencast.com/t/kZkR3wWQakhe

The two countdowns are the same, even tho the dates are different

Comment: How is `Datestring` being populated? You're initializing `count` to the same value of `Datestring`.